# Editing a WMS layer

Tags: qgis, wms, convert, editing, road

For a school project, I'd like to represent the public transport network of our city (using QGIS). I found a WMS layer from an official source, but some bus lines are missing, and others don't exist anymore. So I wanted to try to convert it from a WMS to a vector layer, so I can merge this one with another, and edit them, to have the whole network represented.
But no matter how I tried to do it, nothing works... (and it's been days!)

I'm guessing I need to access the original dataset, to edit the file and create my own layer... Or is there another way to do so ?

Or is there another way to create my own layer, with all the info I'd like te represent? I'm not so good with coding, so if you have an easy way to do it I should be able to understand. Or I'll ask a friend for the translation.

Comment: Check out: https://docs.precisely.com/docs/sftw/stratus/mapinfo_stratus_administration_guide/en/tasks/mapconfig_editing_wmsmap.html

Comment: You might be able to access the underlying WFS data. Check out this blog post by @IanTurton https://blog.ianturton.com/ogc/2022/02/11/WMS-and-WFS.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the underlying data of a WMS, you only see an image from a server. As you write you need the original data.

Comment: You can change the styling of a WMS image, through an SLD or SLD_BODY parameter.